# Linq .Count() does not exist in VB.NET but exists in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

This linq question works excellent in c# and the field **AntalVersioner = d.Count()** works perfekt.

```
List<DokumentModel> result = (from d in response.Values
                                            from c in d
                                            //let dk = response.
                                            select new DokumentMedDatumDTOModel()
                                            {
                                                DokumentId = c.DokumentId,
                                                Forfattare = c.Forfattare,
                                                Kommentar = c.Kommentar,
                                                Nyckelord = c.Nyckelord,
                                                AntalVersioner = d.Count(),
                                                VersionNr = c.VersionNr,
                                                Titel = c.Titel,
                                                SkapadAv = c.SkapadAv,
                                                OriginalFilNamn = c.OriginalFilnamn,
                                                Versions = (from p in d
                                                            select new Version()
                                                            {
                                                                FilUppladdatDatum = p.FilUppladdadDatum,
                                                                OriginalFilNamn = p.OriginalFilnamn,
                                                                SkapadAv = p.SkapadAv,
                                                                Titel = p.Titel,
                                                                VersionNr = p.VersionNr
                                                            }).ToList(),

                                            }).ToList();
```

When Trying to the same thing in VB.NET the **d.Count()** does not exist

```
result = (From dokument In response.Values
            From d In dokument
            Select New DokumentMedDatumDTOModel With {.DokumentId = d.DokumentId, .Forfattare = d.Forfattare, .Kommentar = d.Kommentar, _
                                            .Nyckelord = d.Nyckelord, .VersionNr = d.VersionNr, .Titel = d.Titel, .SkapadAv = d.SkapadAv, _
                                            .OriginalFilNamn = d.OriginalFilnamn, _
                                            .Versions = (From t In dokument
                                                        Select New DokumentVersion With {.Forfattare = t.Forfattare, _
                                                                                        .DokumentId = t.DokumentId, _
                                                                                        .FilUppladdatDatum = t.FilUppladdadDatum, _
                                                                                        .OriginalFilNamn = t.OriginalFilnamn, _
                                                                                        .SkapadAv = t.SkapadAv, _
                                                                                        .Titel = t.Titel, _
                                                                                        .Kommentar = t.Kommentar, _
                                                                                        .Nyckelord = t.Nyckelord, _
                                                                                        .VersionNr = t.VersionNr}).ToList()
                                        }).ToList()
```

Comment: What was the process that generated the VB code?

Comment: You've used very different formatting and a different name, but I don't see in the VB.Net code where you even try to use `dokument.Count`. Also, your title should probably change "does exists" to "doesn't exist" to make sense.

Comment: I get no intellisense when typing **dokument.**

Answer (score 3):

Your two code samples seem to be doing *very* different things on different types.

For example, in C# you create a model:

```
select new DokumentMedDatumDTOModel()
```

But in VB you create a *different* model:

```
Select New DokumentModel
```

So I suspect *a few* things are going to be different between these, regardless of the language being used.

More specific to the question being asked, if `d.Count()` "works" in C#, let's take a look at what `d` is:

```
from d in response.Values
from c in d
```

`d` is an instance from the `response.Values` collection.  But what is it in VB?:

```
From dokument In response.Values
From d In dokument
```

`d` is an instance of the collection of the instances from `response.Values`.  Completely different object.  The "equivalent" of `d.Count()` from this VB code would be:

```
dokument.Count();
```

The compiler doesn't check the *name* of the variable for anything, it just checks the *type of the instance*.  Your `d` variables in the two code samples are entirely different types/instances.

Comment: select new DokumentMedDatumDTOModel() and Select New DokumentModel is a type error in my stackoverflow question. I have changed it to DokumentMedDatumDTOModel

Comment: @user3046164: Either way, it seems a more meaningful use of names would solve/prevent this issue.  The two code samples seem to confuse the definition of things like "document" and use very unhelpful names like "c" and "d" and "p", etc.  Name things by what they semantically and meaningfully represent and the code will read a lot more easily, making bugs a lot easier to find.  For example, `documents.Count()` semantically makes sense because it's the "count" of the "documents".  But `document.Count()` doesn't make sense because a *single* document doesn't have a "count".

Answer (score 0):

Seems hard for me to believe that LINQ which is a framework, works differently for Vb than C#. But maybe it does, however the count function is so fundamental that I have to believe something else is amiss. Just because intellisense doesn't show doesn't mean it's not there. It just means intellisense isn't showing. When it comes to writing LINQ queries, intellisense will quit responding as soon as something in the query isn't right.

Start simple like this.

```
var stuff = db.Customers.ToList();
var count = stuff.Count();
```